# How to Upload Multiple/many image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have problem in my source code, when input many images and different images/ upload file, the results obtained are the same image. how do i fix it, please help me

CONTROLLER

```
public function tambahprogress()
{
    $this->load->helper('url','form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('keterangan','keterangan','trim|required');

    $this->load->model('progress/progress_model');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE) {
        $data['pekerjaan']=$this->progress_model->combopekerjaan();
        $data['pekerja']=$this->progress_model->combopekerja();
        $this->load->view('progress/tambahprogress', $data);
    }else{
        $config['upload_path']      = './assets/upload/';
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']         = 1000000000;
        $config['max_width']        = 10240;
        $config['max_height']       = 7680;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (! $this->upload->do_upload()) 
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('progress/tambahprogress',$error);
        }
        else
        {
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();
            $configer = array (
                'image_library'=>'gd2',
                'source_image'=>$image_data['full_path'],
                'width'=>800,
                'height'=>600,
                );
            $this->load->library('image_lib',$config);
            $this->image_lib->clear();
            $this->image_lib->initialize($configer);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $this->progress_model->insertProgress();
            $this->load->view('progress/tambahprogresssukses');
        }
    }
}
```

MODEL

```
public function insertProgress()
{
    $object = array
    (
        'id_progress' =>$this->input->post('id_progress'), 'no_spk' =>$this->input->post('no_spk'),'progress' =>$this->input->post('progress'), 'keterangan' =>$this->input->post('keterangan'), 'gambar'=>$this->upload->data('file_name'), 'gambar2'=>$this->upload->data('file_name'), 'gambar3'=>$this->upload->data('file_name'), 'id_pekerja' =>$this->input->post('id_pekerja')
    );
    $this->db->insert('progress',$object);
}
```

VIEW(INPUT PROCESS)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Masukkan Gambar</label>
    <<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20"/>
</div>
```

and the result is same images but when i input data, i input different image please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $config['upload_path'] = PATH; //add path according to your requirements 
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
 $config['overwrite'] = false; //OR true
 $config['max_size'] = '100000'; //You can change it
 //add more configuration according to your requirements 
 $this->load->library('upload');
 $files = $_FILES;
 $number_of_files = count($_FILES['pic']['name']); //"pic" is name of FILE input 
 //images name will be details0, details1, details2 and soo on.
 $errors = 0;
 for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
 $_FILES['pic']['name'] = "details" . $i . ".jpg"; //If you want to change the name of images change "details" with your require name
 $_FILES['pic']['type'] = $files['pic']['type'][$i];
 $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'] = $files['pic']['tmp_name'][$i];
 $_FILES['pic']['error'] = $files['pic']['error'][$i];
 $_FILES['pic']['size'] = $files['pic']['size'][$i];
 $this->upload->initialize($config);
 if (!$this->upload->do_upload("pic")) 
 {
   $errors++;
 }
} 
if ($errors > 0) 
{
   echo $errors . "File(s) could not be uploaded";
}
```

Comment: how with view ? correct?

Comment: use this for multiple image selection <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="pic[]"  />

Comment: image selection <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="pic[]" /> this just one or three, like  image selection <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="pic[]" />  image selection <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="pic[]" /> image selection <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="pic[]" /> to upload 3 pic ?

Comment: You can select your three pics only with this code. add only one time bro

Comment: oh i see, how about model? right or not ? @DanishAli

Comment: You do not need to add $this->upload->data('file_name') to store in DB because images never store in it

Comment: You can store image name and also image path but not image.

Comment: Images already uploaded so You do not need to add $this->upload->data('file_name') in array to store in DB because images never store in it

Comment: so i need table for images or not ? in model when insert "'gambar'=>$this->input->post('gambar')" one syntax for 3 pic on 1 table ?

Comment: images will move/upload in your path. you will show image like this {<?php echo base_url(). 'images-path' ;?>}

Comment: you do not need any table for images. only need images name and path.

Comment: ok thankyou @DanishAli

Comment: give me upvote for answer